# how to read a file from a declared directory

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I have declared a directory to store some of my files.

I need to access that directory? How can I do that?

Is it possible wit NSString?

Thanks..

Is there any examples around?

Comment: What do you mean by "declared a directory"?

Comment: I have declared a directory called "directoryPath" in which all my files will go into that directory. I want to acces a file from that directory. How would I do that? Did you understand?

Answer (score 0):

You might use NSString's `-stringByAppendingPathComponent:` to construct file paths and `+stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` to read the file's content into an NSString. See the documentation for these and similar methods for more details.